# JavaScript RegEx On Styles

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove all "color" style from element style using regex but I am failing miserably.

Example of a style

```
cursor: pointer;background-color: yellow;color: lightgray;
```

Example of what the style should become

```
cursor: pointer;background-color: yellow;
```

This is the regex I am using `color:[^;]+;`

It captures background-color and removes the part after background.

Comment: Please read the [regex] tag : you should always precise the tool you use.

Comment: I did include regex and regularexpression tag.

Comment: Yes but you should also *"include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using"* (see tag description).

Comment: Done. I thought RegEx was standard no matter what programming language you use.

Comment: No, there are flavors and some advanced features aren't available in javascript for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex works for me :

```
[\s;]color:[^;]+(?=;)|^color:[^;]+;
```

You'll see it handles differently the case where the color is the first parameter.

```
var style = "cursor: pointer;background-color: yellow;color: lightgray;";
var replaced = style.replace(/[\s;]color:[^;]+(?=;)|^color:[^;]+;/g, '')
```

Note that, even if using a regex isn't that bad here, this operation could be done with greater confidence with a simple splitting+filtering :

```
var replaced = style.split(';').filter(function(v){
   return v.split(':')[0].trim()!='color'
}).join(';');
```

Comment: This is bad news if color is not the first or last element (since it will remove both the leading and trailing semicolon).

Comment: I'm sure a shorter regex could be found but come on, why 2 downvotes ?

Comment: +1, To down voters, I suspect that you're thinking to yourself 'CSS shouldn't be parsed with RegExp', you're wrong.
CSS is a very simple and **regular** language which means regular expressions are a good option to parse it.

Comment: I downvoted because the original regex was broken, removed it now that it is fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the tidy code. Shame there isn't a way to just do it with replace with first splitting the style

Answer (score 0):

A little update on the solution.

dystroy, solution just has one small issue dealing with backgroud-image with base64 input. Just wanted to add regular expression for splitting the style

```
arr = s.match(/background-image\s*:\s*url\s*\(\s*data:image[^)]+\)?|[a-zA-Z-]+:[^;]+/gi);
```

That should give you an array containing all the elements. So far it works.